# More efficient way to make dynamic sql queries than iteration

Tags: python, mysql, performance, iteration, query-optimization

I have to make multiple sql queries of entire tables, and concatenate them into one big data table.

I have a dictionary where the key is a team name, and the value serves as an acronym where the acronym is the prefix to mySQL data tables

```
    engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://%s:%s@%s/%s' % (mysql_user, mysql_password, mysql_host, mysql_dbname), echo=False, pool_recycle=1800)
    
    mysql_conn = engine.connect()
    
    team_dfs = []
    
    nba_dict = {'New York Knicks': 'nyk',
        'Boston Celtics': 'bos',
        'Golden State Warriors': 'gsw',
        'New York Knicks': 'nyk'}
    
        for name, abbr in nba_dict.items()
    
            query = f'''
            SELECT *
            from {abbr}_record
            '''
            df = pd.read_sql_query(query, mysql_conn)

            df['team_name'] = name
    
            team_dfs.append(df)
    
    team_dfs = pd.concat(team_dfs)
```

Is there a better way to refactor this code and make it more efficient?

Comment: Don't separate records per team if you are going to query them together. Avoid `select *`. Don't try to preemptively optimize your code around the data. Get the database with structured data and the performance and simple code will flow from that.

Comment: 100% agree. I'm not the DB admin, and the goal of the above task is to create a gold layer table where all this data is combined in one place.

Comment: Since this is a one-time task to fix a broken schema, does efficiency matter?

Answer (score 1):

Your database layout, with a separate table for each team, is *doomed to inefficiency* whenever you need to retrieve data for more than one team at a time. You would be much *much* better off putting all that data in one table, giving the table a column mentioning the team associated with each row.

Why inefficient?  More tables: more work.  And, more queries: more work.

I suggest you push back, *hard*, on the designer of this database table structure. Its design is, bluntly, wrong.

If you must live with this structure, I suggest you create the following view. It will fake the single-table approach and give you your "gold layer". You get away with this because pro sports franchises don't come and go that often. You do this just once in your database.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW teams_record AS
SELECT 'nyk' team, * FROM nyk_record
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bos' team, * FROM bos_record
UNION ALL
SELECT 'gsw' team, * FROM gsw_record
UNION ALL .... the other teams
```

Then you can do `SELECT * FROM teams_record ORDER BY team` to get all your data.

Answer (score 0):

If your `nba_dict` is fixed, you can use `UNION` to manually combine the result table of SQL.

```
abbr = list(nba_dict.values())

query = f'''
SELECT *
from {abbr[0]}_record UNION
SELECT *
from {abbr[1]}_record UNION
SELECT *
from {abbr[2]}_record UNION
SELECT *
from {abbr[3]}_record UNION
'''
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, mysql_conn)
df['team_name'] = list(nba_dict.keys())
```

Comment: Is this a more efficient method, performance wise to go about this? Since in this case, you're making one big query, rather than 7 separate queries.

Comment: What are your definitions of efficiency and performance???

Comment: My definition is speed

Comment: `UNION` deduplicates. `UNION ALL` doesn't. Deduplication is probably not the right way to go here.